# Plotting 1000 points (following a particular probability distribution) on the USA map

Tags: matlab, plot

I got the following code from mathworks that plots a map of the USA:

```
 figure; ax = usamap('conus');
    states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
      'Selector',...
      {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',...
        {'INDEX', [1 numel(states)], 'FaceColor', ... 
        polcmap(numel(states))}); %NOTE - colors are random
    geoshow(ax, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', ...
       'SymbolSpec', faceColors)
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
```

I would appreciate if someone can kindly help me with the following:
I want to plot 1000 points following a probability distribution (say Exponential for now, but can be modified for any other distribution) distributed over the USA. These cluster-points need to be distinguishable from the background color and big enough. furthermore, I would like to be able to get the coordinates of these points 1000 point "(x,y)" for other calculations. I will appreciate any help regarding this. Also, if the USA code can be made much more efficient and mayble include the Quebec state of canada then that would be much appreciated as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a set of random coordinates and remember that the coordinates should be in the range (boundaries) of the map:
Let's say your range in x direction is [xmin xmax]
and in y direction it is [ymin ymax].

The min ana max values should be extracted from the map.
this is what I have extracted.
1-If you just use the poor image:

```
xmax = 2.354e6;
ymax = 5.478e6;
xmin = -1.984e6;
ymin = 2.674e6;
```

2- If you use map:

```
 v=[];
 allLat=[v states(:).LabelLat];
 allLon=[v states(:).LabelLon];
 xmin = min(allLon);
 xmax = max(allLon);
 ymin = min(allLat);
 ymax = max(allLat);
```

then you should generate values from the uniform distribution on the interval [a, b]. The general form is like this:

```
% r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1); % don't need to run this line
```

And you can create the 1000 randomly distributed points using the following commands:

```
X = xmin + (xmax-xmin).*rand(1000,1);
Y = ymin + (ymax-ymin).*rand(1000,1);
```

Now you have your randomly created points, then the easy part is to plot the points. before that you need to check that the point is inside the specific map.

```
function v = checkPoint(x,y) 
b = zeros(size(landareas));
for i = 1:max(size(landareas))
    if x >= landareas(i).BoundingBox(1,1) && x <= landareas(i).BoundingBox(2,1) && y >=       landareas(i).BoundingBox(1,2) && y <= landareas(i).BoundingBox(2,2) 
    b(i) = 1;
end
end
v = ~isempty(find(b==1))
```

(the above function is not optimized though)

so you check your points using the "checkPoint" function and if the return value is v = 1, then you plot the point otherwise you ignore the point. now you can use the below command:

```
plot(X,Y,'oy','MarkerSize',10)
```

Also you can use X and Y vectors later for any calculations.

Finally you can plot any part of the world you like using this code:

```
worldmap({'Canada','Usa'})
land = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(land, 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15])
cities = shaperead('worldcities', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(cities, 'Marker', '.', 'Color', 'red')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i am not able to see how to include the quebec state in the map and also what is the range in the mathworks plot (i.e., [a b])...can you please suggest something for these..thank you very much, again!

Comment: Also, can you please tell me the significance of 
r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1); in the calculations for X, Y?
Sorry, I am not able to see.

Comment: The "rand" comand creates random numbers in the range of [0 1]. so you need to map this value to your map's scale. Otherwise having random numbers in the range [0 1] in this case is useless.

Comment: Thanks so very much. I wasn't bale to do that. Just two last things:
1. What is the significance of r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);
2. Can you please help me in anyway to include the quebec state...I tried my best to search online but I didn't have any luck in finding USA with quebec. 
Sorry for the bother again.

Comment: The r=a+(b-a)*rand(100,1) is just an example that shows the formula better. For Quebec I don't know. In addition, after running your code in Matlab you will have an structure called "states". you can open that structure in MapViewer App by Matlab. Then you can move the mouse over the map and see the coordinate is changing.

Comment: thank you so much. Hopefully, I figure out the Quebec part or someone can help.

Comment: check my answer again, I found sth maybe useful.

Comment: Thanks again. I am still having problems in the markers appearing on the US map? After I computed the X,Y vectors -- I tried plotting the markers on but it doesn't seem to appear on it. I did "hold on" as well, but didn't work. Also, can you please tell me how to use the function "checkpoint" so that it automatically checks and plots it directly -- or do I need to check it for each one? Sorry about the bother again and appreciate the help.

Comment: The markers appeared on the map when I used the points you initially extracted from the map, but they are not all on the map (some are off). Can you please tell me how to use the function properly and also how to use the map (2) -- that would be fantastic.

Comment: if you are using the first extracted points then commands like Plot and hold on, works well. but when you use the Lat and Lon values then you should use "geoshow" command to plot the markers for your points.

Comment: You can use the function either inside a for loop or change the function to accept vectors as input. Obviously the first method is slower but in this size of data it won't be sensible.